# count() yields a warning if NULL from PHP 7.2. Is there a better way of fixing this for PHP 5.6+ than adding another condition?

Tags: php, php-7.2

For example:

```
if (count($this->implements) > 0)
```

will produce a warning. I can always do this:

```
if (!is_null($this->implements) && count($this->implements) > 0)
```

But is there an easier and better way of fixing this? It has to be fully backward compatible with PHP 5.6, too.

Comment: How about `if (!empty($this->implements))`?

Comment: I tried to use count(NULL) and have no error, what error you have?

Comment: What do you want to happen with an array containing `null` values?

Comment: @Vykintas it's not an error but a Warning. Check your php error log or turn xdebug on.

Comment: @Martin absolutely nothing, it skips it if its NULL.

Answer (score 2):

A fudge would be to use [null coalesce(`??`)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to set it to an empty array if null...

```
if (count($this->implements??[]) > 0)
```

Comment: unfortunately it has to be still backwards compatible and `??` was added in PHP 7 I believe. Just tested, and it doesn't work with 5.6

Comment: Just curious as to why you are using 5.6 as well?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi It's a open-source library that I'm doing some pull requests for. It should be compatible from 5.6 upwards as it is used in many different projects, running on different PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). It'll return true if the property does not exist (without raising "Notice") or is falsy (an empty array is falsy):

```
if (empty($this->implements) === false) {
}
```

Comment: OP is using count... he needs to replace count with empty.

Comment: oops, I saw that as a additional rarter than a replacement. Plus one. `;-)`

Comment: This is probably the best solution, although I have now fixed it in the code differently. All I had to do is to initialise `$this->implements` as an empty `array()`. It is always going to be an array and this fixes the WARNING issue. If he saw this, my .NET colleague would again shake his head and try to convince me to learn a strongly typed language ...

Answer (score 0):

> count() will yield a warning if NULL from PHP 7.2. Is there a better way of fixing this than adding another condition?

## YES

The solution is to force the argument to be an array:

```
if (count((array)$this->implements) > 0)
```

This works on PHP 5 and 7, all versions  up to 7.2.4 tested. No Error log entries where found.

Comment: @SalmanA OP has not qualified that the property would ever *not* exist, simply that it may sometimes be `null`. And a **notice** level error is a significant step down from a **warning** level.

Comment: count happily accepts non-arrays. count(null) -> 0. Most likely OP is talking about _Notice: undefined property foo::$implements_.

Comment: @SalmanA in PHP 7.2 it throws a *WARNING*, please see [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php).